Get variable stored at specific memory address in Java
I am working with a Java instrumentation framework (DiSL) to profile some code. I am retrieving the values of local variables at various stages of execution, however some of them are only accessible as their memory locations, e.g. for a local var that is a char[], it returns an address like [C@7f9a81e8. Is there a way to "dereference" that address, i.e. get the value of the variable that is stored there?
I was told that Java Reflection API could provide some necessary functionality, however I could not find relevant functions there, but I could have not looked well enough. My project is built with maven and JDK17. Will appreciate any advise. Thanks in advance.

[C@7f9a81e8 isn't an address but means a character array ([C) with a specific identity hashcode (7f9a81e8). The string you get is normally generated by the default implementation of toString(). If the profiling tool you're using doesn't provide a reference to those instances directly you might need to look into overriding toString(). There might be easier ways though but for those you'd need to elaborate on what exactly you're doing.

That is not a memory address, so no, you can't dereference this.

I assumed that the question wanted to find the address of the variable, not deference the string name directly, but yes taken literally that string simply isn't an address.  Maybe the OP can clarify why they think finding an address is important?

If you want to get or set elements of arrays reflectively, use the methods of java.lang.reflect.Array.  (javadoc)  You can also do it using MethodHandles.

Aside: why are you using byte code instrumentation to profile code?  Dedicated, and very functional, profilers exist: https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers

Thanks all for comments/suggestions so far. Is anyone able to cite any resource that talks about those identity hashcodes?

@markspace Thank you however I have tried almost all of the ones cited on that Baeldung article and found they are not very suitable for my project as none of them provide a straightforward way to read vars at different stages of execution. I'm not exactly a pro so it could be that I misused them

The format is described at the toString() method itself (which all classes including arrays inherit when not overridden). Part of the described format is the result of hashCode() which results in an identity hash code if not overridden.

Thanks all for the comments. I tried a few of the suggestions and in the end overwriting the toString() method was the best solution.
